# Sitefinity 9.1 - Custom Profile provider?

Tags: sitefinity

I'm looking into a custom membership provider in Sitefinity 9.1 to manage users from an external API. However, we'd also like to manage user profiles externally. I haven't seen any documentation on how to also create a custom profile provider. Any help would be appreciated!